# how to count number of pairs with si<sj for any given i in O(1) for array s

Tags: c++

```
for(int k=0; k<n-1 ; k++)
{
    for(int l=k+1; l<n; l++)
    {
        if(s[k]<s[l])
            count = count+1;
    }
}
```

This code has O(n²) complexity. How can it be improved?

Comment: it is impossible using single processor/core

Comment: What makes you think this can be done in O(1) time? Or did you mean O(1) space?

Comment: Does `i` have to be less than `j`?

Answer (score 2):

*If* you are guaranteed all elements in the array unique, then this is very simple.  The number of `s[i]-s[j]`pairs in which `s[i] < s[j]` is going to be the (n-1)th [triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) number, where `n` is the number of elements in the array.  See the following simple table of the elements `{0, 1, 2, 3}`.  Rows designate `s[i]`, columns designate `s[j]`

```
   0   1   2   3
0  =   <   <   <
1  >   =   <   <
2  >   >   =   <
3  >   >   >   =
```

We are looking for the numbers in which `s[i]` is less than `s[j]` - as you can see , this is the upper-right triangle of the table.  This will always be true *so long as all the elements are unique*.

To calculate the triangular number, it is `(n - 1) * n / 2`

Answer (score -1):

**Use quick sort algorithm.** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

Each time a separation is made with the pivot you can count the amount of pairs with the size of the two parts.

Each value of one side makes a pair with each value of the other side, in other terms, it is `p*(n - p)` where `n` is the size of the table, and `p` the position of the pivot.

Sum this value every times a separation occurs.

Example:

```
[ 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1,  9, 7, 9, 8 ]
  -------------------   ----------
          (p)         *   (n - p)
```

Comment: This is at least linear O(n). Not O(1)